# PowerShell function outputing unexpected extra newline

Tags: powershell

Here is a piece of function I'm trying to create to make my testing faster:

```
function t++ {
    param($Source, $Input, $Output)
    ...
    g++ $Source -o test;
    .\test.exe
    Write-Output "===End-Of-Output==="
}
```

But the output in my Windows PowerShell ISE comes as:

```
Hello, World!
===End-Of-Output===
\n
```

(the last line is blank)

I can't understand why is it outputting that extra newline after the End-Of-Output.

Comment: Is this something you observe in the shell? Or when you output to a file? If so, how did you output to a file? PowerShell's formatting subsystem loves to add extra space when outputting to the host (in your case, probably the console)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Could you make sure you're not leaving anything out from the function, and show how you're calling it? Is it being called any another function?

Comment: Aww damn it! I'm sorry, I was testing this in the Windows PowerShell ISE.
Now I tested it in the actual PowerShell and it worked fine. Should have double-checked... but why the hell the PowerShell ISE outputs it differently?

Comment: @VillasV PowerShell ISE doesn't use the `console`, it reimplements its own output mechanics. Think of it as having an extra `\n` before your prompt in `$PS1` in a bourne-style shell - the output is the same but once it hits the screenbuffer, a line is added

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen If you write that as an answer I'll accept it gladly. Spent too much time trying to solve a non-existing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When output is written to the standard output stream in PowerShell, it's picked up by the [Host application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx) - and the host application may format and manipulate the output.

In case of `powershell.exe` that would be `System.Console`, rendering string output *as is*, but a PowerShell Host application is not *necessarily* `Console`-based.

PowerShell ISE for example, doesn't use `System.Console`, since the output pane is also your debugger - I assume the PowerShell development team found it easier to implement a new output mechanism rather than extending `Console`.